# Ruby Rails - add a boolean checkbox column into existing db and how do i work with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do i add a boolean true false column to existing database with default value false? (lets say checkbox for user_agreement)

my existing table:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
end
```

what shoud i do after that? should i do something like this?

html:

```
<%= check_box_tag "user_agreement[]" %>
```

controller:

```
if params[:user_agreement] == '1'
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    user.update_attribute(:user_agreement, true)
    flash[:success] = "accepted agreement"
else
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    user.update_attribute(:user_agreement, false)
    flash[:success] = "didn't accepted agreement"
end
```

Comment: have a look here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to run a migration to add the column `user_agreement` to your **User** model:

```
$ rake generate migration AddUserAgreementToUsers user_agreement:boolean
```

Open up the migration file you just generated and add the default of `false`:

**db/migrate/_add_user_agreement_to_users.rb**

```
class AddUserAgreementToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :people, :user_agreement, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Run the migration to make the changes to the database:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

If you're running Rails 4 you'll need to add `user_agreement` to the list of parameters you'll accept:

```
private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :user_agreement)
  end
```

And finally add `user_agreement` to your form.

**app/views/users/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user %>
  ...
  <%= f.check_box :user_agreement %>
  ...
<% end %>
```